# firefox css option style wont work

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to change my option select box styles using CSS.

Everything works fine in Google Chrome but the styles do not work in Mozilla Firefox.

What am I missing here to work my CSS code also in Mozilla Firefox?

Can anyone help me with this regard?

```css
.container {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:500px;
   margin:0px auto;
   margin-top:100px;
   padding:40px;
   background-color:#fafafa;
   border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.i_bd  select {
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255,1) !important;
   border-radius:3px;
   -webkit-border-radius:3px;
   -moz-border-radius:3px;
   padding:18px;
   color:#333333;
   font-size:13px;
   font-weight:500;
   outline:none;
   border: 1px solid rgba(239, 239, 239, 1);
   width:80px;
   height:30px; 

}

.i_bd {
     -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    position: relative;
 float:left;
 margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="i_bd">
      <select name="select">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: `<select>` elements are generally really difficult to style, due to a combination of both vendor- and OS-specific styling that is already in place. You might want to set `appearance: none` (remember to also add the vendor-prefixed variants), and add the arrow as a background-image, for example.

Comment: Add -moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;appearance:none; and add arrow by adding outer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment: `<select>` elements are known to be notoriously difficult to style, due to interfering OS- and vendor-specific styles. The best way is simply to reset the element entirely, using the `appearance` property and setting it to `none`, and then using a background-image in place of the dropdown arrow.

The other issue with your styles is that you have a padding of `18px` declared on the select element, but it's height is only `30px`. This causes the content to have no space (in fact, -6px) to be displayed. If you reduce vertical padding to a lower value, the text will show. In this case, I have use `padding: 4px 18px`.

In the proof-of-concept example below, I have used [Google Material Icon's dropdown arrow](https://material.io/icons/#ic_arrow_drop_down) that is converted into base64 code. You can easily convert any SVG into base64 using [this site](http://b64.io/).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #d8dbdf;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.i_bd select {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;

  /* Ensure that top/bottom padding is reduced! */
  padding: 4px 18px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(239, 239, 239, 1);
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  
  /* Disable vendor-specific appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  
  /* Use triangle background as arrow */
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBmaWxsPSIjMDAwMDAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjI0IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjQgMjQiIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4gICAgPHBhdGggZD0iTTcgMTBsNSA1IDUtNXoiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
}

.i_bd {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
  -ms-flex-negative: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="i_bd">
    <select name="select">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is here, when i select 4 it is not showing 4 is selected. Stil empty in selectbox

Comment: @DevStud That has to do with your vertical padding on the select element, if you reduce it, the text will appear. See updated answer.